# Spark scala dataframe groupby

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this dataframe and I want to create another one like the expected one. The thing is that I want to take the values of col_2 of the same group 'a' of col_1 and put them in the same row in distinct columns. Is there a way to do it?

```
#+-----+-----+-----+-
#|col_1| id  |col_2| 
#+-----+-----+-----+
#|    a|    1|    c|
#|    a|    2|    f|
#|    a|    3|    i|
#+-----+-----+-----+
```

Expected

```
#+-----+-----+-----+-------+
#|col_1|col_c|col_f| col_i |
#+-----+-----+-----+-------+
#|    a|  c  | f   |  i    | 
 +-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your dataset is called `main`. We can use the following query to extract the values as columns:

```
var created = main.groupBy("col_1").pivot("col_2").agg(first(col("col_2")))
```

This gives this output (which is almost as you like):

```
+-----+---+---+---+
|col_1|  c|  f|  i|
+-----+---+---+---+
|    a|  c|  f|  i|
+-----+---+---+---+
```

Now, we find the columns that do not start with `col_` and we rename them in the dataset:

```
val columns = created.columns.filterNot(c => c.startsWith("col_"))

for (i <- columns) {
  created = created.withColumnRenamed(i, "col_" + i)
}
```

Final output:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_c|col_f|col_i|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    c|    f|    i|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```